# Does "potential" word always indicate a positive meaning

Tags: grammar

I just want to ask if the word "potential" always shows some sort of positive meaning?

For example, if the question is:
Q: what is the potential of/for.... ?

Now, can it be answered in this way ...
A: The potential is low, less or minimum.. etc..

Answer (score 2):

Someone or something can have a potential for either good or bad. The potential can be high or low. Thus
Good and high

> Joe has the potential to become a great singer, he's just won the competition.

Good and low

> Jim has little potential to become a singer, he can't follow a tune.

Bad and high

> That storm has the potential to become a hurricane.

Bad and low

> Sam had no potential to be a successful thief, he got caught too often.